# I do not receive proper support from my PhD advisor

Tags: advisor, supervision

I have started my fully-funded-PhD for about 6 months in North America. When I applied professor promised me that he was going to provide me with the funding.  Yet, I have not received any detailed topic about my PhD from my supervisor.

I see my other classmates have already got projects with secure funding. I have not received any secure project yet, and my funding is not stable(so far I have received only $12500), my bank is currently -$10000, and I had to pay the tuition fee.

The amount fund received so far: $12500

My spending so far: food, housing, and tuition fee: $18800

I needed to borrow an extra $10000 from my family to pay my expenses.

Each time that I have a meeting with him, he just comes and talks about some general topics about his projects and he does not assign anything.

I tried to communicate this during my meeting but it was not effective, seems like he does not understand my needs. How do I write him an email and communicate this with him? "I need a problem definition/ project with secure funding from a company so that I can work on it, It is really frustrating for me to see everyone is working on their project"

How do I write him an email to effectively communicate my thoughts? I feel like my words may not be heard as intended.

Comment: Assuming you won't get the funding, do you have alternatives?

Comment: "_my bank is currently -$10000_" You have $10000 debt or you still have $10000 balance in the bank ? Please clarify. If you owe $10000, how much was the tuition you had to pay ?

Comment: I edited the post, I needed to borrow an extra 10k from family.

Comment: Is your supervisor supposed to give you a topic or you are free to choose a topic ?

Comment: Obviously, I can not find a topic since he provides funding and is aware of the problems. I just want him to engage me in a project.

Comment: @programmer_smart That sounds like a horrible situation and I’m sorry. Some questions: 1. Did you not sign a contract at the start of your PhD with a salary amount in it? 2. Who is your official employer? 3.do you expect the funding to come from the university, your Pi, or a company? 4. Did anyone tell you that the funding was tied to finding a research project?

Comment: Either your PhD is not actually fully funded, or you have failed to bring this to the attention of the right people, who might include administrative staff for the grad program, a department chair, etc.

Comment: Funding and project are not quite so intertwined as you imply; you can easily have a project but no funding or funding but no project. It seems like the funding, not the project, is the more immediate issue so work on that first.

Comment: Which country is this?

Comment: Have you told him you'd like to have a meeting specifically about funding?

Comment: OP, you mentioned that you "see" that your classmates have projects with funding. Have you spoken to them and asked how they got to this point?

Comment: "I do not receive proper support from my PhD advisor" <- A very common situation unfortunately.

Answer (score 32):

To be honest, it sounds like you are entirely too passive in this situation, expecting that the advisor will simply "give" you something. While I don't know your field, that would be very unusual in many.

You have had conversations with the advisor. Does anything in those conversations pique your interest in a problem to be researched. My guess is that the advisor expects that to happen.

A PhD isn't just an employee working under the explicit direction of a manager, carrying out assigned tasks. It requires some creativity and initiative.

Not everyone can come up with their own problem, but having some idea of a possible problem opens the opportunity for a conversation with the advisor that, with refinement, can lead to one. Open that conversation and not with email. This is a situation that calls for face to face discussions and explorations.

I suggest that you don't sit back and expect things to happen automatically. Get busy.

Comment: " It requires some creativity and initiative." Totally agree!

Comment: While this is a good advice, it does not answer his question.

Comment: @lr0, I've made it a bit more explicit. Email is a poor vehicle for this.

Comment: I cannot see how the question of funding (money) enter this answer. Or, this is already not important in academia?

Comment: @yarchik, my reading is that funding is tied to the specific research. The funding will follow from finding an appropriate project. That isn't universally true, but seems to be the case here.

Comment: There is a lot of assumptions in your answer. While I fully agree with you that one must show initiative, not only in science, in any job actually, there are formal requirements. Being initiative is never a precondition for a working contract. For this, there are evaluations. You pass the evaluation and your contract is prolonged. Or you do not pass and the contract is terminated. These are the conditions set at the beginning.

Comment: @yarchik the OP hasn't asked about money, they asked about how best to elicit a response from their supervisor. Coming up with a research idea would do that; the OP could approach their supervisor with a topic, then the supervisor would be forced to give feedback and clarify what needs to be done.

Comment: @isolatedmatrix Having 10K debt and no working contract, to come up with creative research ideas begging for unclear something would be the last thing for me to do. No contract, no money -- no job done.

Comment: @yarchik then perhaps you should post an answer suggesting what you *would* do. Either way, the question was not about money.

Answer (score 6):

> How do I write him an email to effectively communicate my thoughts? I
> feel like my words may not be heard as intended.

You don not write an email. You meet him in the office, you pester him with phone calls, you read your contract and you escalate to the head of department.

You have plenty of hints that he is not getting your needs. You need to sit at the same table to discuss face to face. Be calm and polite, bring him to understand your situation.

"I apologize but I do not have much quality time to think about our research because I have to compare all this APR loan options to sustain myself" can be a good ice-breaker.

Comment: I've voted down because the advisor would be able to say this to their boss : "I'm being pestered by this crazy person.  He's always ringing me, no matter what I say."

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine "no matter what you say, but what did you do?"

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.  I do know that pestering someone with phone calls is not going to be considered reasonable behavior by the organization employing the advisor.  That would likely solve the OP's problem (kind of), because the organization would most likely end his PhD for pestering staff.

Comment: @StephenG-HelpUkraine you have a very simplistic view of the world. Glad it works for you.

Comment: All your advice would do is make the OP look confrontational while leaving them without written evidence of the problem, as you particularly say they should not email.  That won't work well for anyone in dispute with any organization.  Writing in email also allows people to make considered responses that, if they make the effort) are phrased well.  This can reduce the problem of not saying what you need to in a conversation and not using ambiguous language - something that's very prone to happen in face to face conversation.  Heated phone calls (inevitable if you "pester" someone) won't help.

Comment: All your advice would do is make OP unhappy and believing in a future project that will solve their future economic problem. Sure, with a paper trail, very useful to present to the bank when they ask to refund the taken loans.
Congratulations nonetheless for explaining me what is already in my answer.

Comment: An email is a useful record when escalating to the head of department or other parts of the university/institute - "I specified x problems at y time and it is documented here." It's impossible to evidence what was said on a phone call. At the very least emailing after the phone call/meeting you describe with the contents of the discussion is useful.

Comment: @JayBee totally agree, but this is not the question of OP.  Unfortunately we are already in the realm of "oral promises" ( *When I applied professor promised me that he was going to provide me with the funding.*) so a paper trail is of little help, OP is looking for the professor to concretize the promises ... hard thing to do ...